# how to increace font size in iphone , ipad mini and ipad tablet

Tags: xamarin.forms, xlabs, xamarin.forms.labs

i am using **Xlabs font manager** and font provider to increase font size 
i got success in that but only the problem i am facing in iPad-mini no change in font size. i used bellow code to change font size

```
   private const short InitialSize = 18;

    /// <summary>
    /// Finds the closest.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="name">The name.</param>
    /// <param name="desiredHeight">Height of the desired.</param>
    /// <returns>Font.</returns>
    public Font FindClosest(string name, double desiredHeight)
    {
        var height = this.GetHeight(Font.OfSize(name, InitialSize));

        var multiply = (int)((desiredHeight / height) * InitialSize);


        var f1 = Font.OfSize(name, multiply);
        var f2 = Font.OfSize(name, multiply + 1);

        var h1 = this.GetHeight(f1);
        var h2 = this.GetHeight(f2);

        var d1 = Math.Abs(h1 - desiredHeight);
        var d2 = Math.Abs(h2 - desiredHeight);

        return d1 < d2 ? f1 : f2;
    }
```

iPhone and ipad Font size is look perfect but iPad mini Font size is looks  too small
[image: iPhone Font Size]

[image: iPad Font Size]

[image: iPad Mini Font Size]

is it correct code?

Answer (score 2):

You can try using a standard font size instead of do calculation according to screen size. Try this:

```
label.FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Small, typeof(Label));
```

You can either set it to small, medium, big. I find this quite useful for my app. Check [this link](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/fonts/) for more details.